# How to stop ArgumentOutOfRangeException in following method

Tags: c#

The following code give the ArgumentOutOfRangeException when I try to use it to test my strings if they contain characters other than numbers and alphabets.

Guess it makes sense considering the line I marked with the comment will run over the bounds at the last index. How do I resolve this cos I can't possibly start off with (i-1, i) nor (i,i). Please advice. Thanks.

```
public static bool LegalString(string s)
        {
            string dict = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
            for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
            {
                if (!dict.Contains(s.Substring(i, 1).ToLower()))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("'" + s.Substring(i, i + 1).ToLower() + "'");//Line that is giving the error
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
```

EDIT:

```
if (!LegalString(name))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Entry for name. Enter only numbers and alphabets.");
            }
```

I am using the method as above. It will work fine if I enter a name for example: Sam.

If I enter for example, Sam/// it will return the exception when I am expecting the messagebox to appear instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the `i + 1` within this line that's the issue:

```
Console.WriteLine("'" + s.Substring(i, i + 1).ToLower() + "'");//Line that is giving the error
```

If you're trying to display the substring that isn't within the comparison string, you need to change the line to this:

```
Console.WriteLine("'" + s.Substring(i, 1).ToLower() + "'");//Line that is giving the error
```

**EDIT:**

I modified your method to have the following and it works as expected with the input string of "Sam//". i.e. it returns `false`:

```
public static bool LegalString(string s)
{
    string dict = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
    {
        if (!dict.Contains(s.Substring(i, 1).ToLower()))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: (i,1) allows any symbols. // returns true

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  I'm explaining that the exception you're getting comes from the `Substring(i, i + 1)`.  I'm not sure what you're trying to display if the substring doesn't match.

Comment: I just want to display a messagebox saying "invalid entry" if substring doesn't match.

Comment: I swapped the information to (i,1). If I enter Sam, it works fine.  If I enter Sam//something it displays the messagebox which is correct. When I enter Sam// , nothing happens. When In fact I should be getting the error message too.

Comment: Ok, so you've got 2 issues: 1) Fixing the exception (done)  2) Handling the case of "Sam//"

Comment: when I stick to the initial (i, i+1) the exception occurs for Sam// too. I believe rectifying the exception is the only issue.

Comment: I updated my answer with the code that I was able to get to return the correct value.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the loop altogether, and [use a built-in function to test for letter or digit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cay4xx2f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), like this:

```
public static bool LegalString(string s) {
    if (!s.All(Char.IsLetterOrDigit)) {
        Console.WriteLine( "'{0}'", s.First(c => !Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c)));
        return false;
    }
    return true;        
}
```

Note that the built-in function allows other alphanumeric characters that are not included in your `dict` string. If this is not desirable, you could plug in your own function for checking the correctness of individual characters.

Comment: that is correct but it doesn't perform the same thing with OP's code.it allows more than those characters

Comment: @Selman22 What do you meant by *it allows more than those characters*?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel The `Char.IsLetterOrDigit` allows characters that represent digits and letters in alphabets other than Latin. I edited the answer to mention this.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel it seems the OP wants to allow all characters in the latin alphabet and the digits (from 0 to 9), but char.IsLetterOrDigit return true for more than that,see the documentation

Comment: @dasblinkenlight By that it would mean using the built in method plus write another method similar to mine to verify that. I am guessing it would be better to stick with one method instead..

Answer (score 0):

As an aside, rather that look through `dict` each time you could write a function like this:

```
bool IsValidChar(char c)
{
  return char.IsDigit(c) || (c>='a' && c<='z') || (c>='A' && c<='Z');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression instead...

```
private static bool ContainsNonAlphanumeric(string s)
{
    Regex pattern = new Regex(@"\W|_");
    if(pattern.IsMatch(s))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Have a look at this fiddle... http://dotnetfiddle.net/g2YAT0

Answer (score 0):

What is the expect output in the line `Console.WriteLine("'" + s.Substring(i, i + 1).ToLower() + "'")`. That is the error, you are expecting a sub string with the lenght i + 1. I don't think so. Maybe should be s.Lenght - i, just 1.
Check it out.

Comment: tried both s.length-1 and s.length-2 and they return same error.